# Can I use another file to extend wp-config.php in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, configuration

As the title says, I would like to create another file for WordPress, for example, it could be **wp-config-more.php** where this file will be run after **wp-config.php**.

I am at a loss and could not find how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at wp-config.php itself and see how external files are included, and do it the same way. There isn't a way to hook into wp-config.php with a function because what the file does is very low level and happens before any theme functions.

I.e., at the end of wp-config.php is

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

So try

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config-more.php');`

with a `wp-config-more.php` file in root.

Not the greatest idea to do this in anything more for your own site. It's akin to modifying core WP files, which is not a good habit to take.

And this might possibly not work if you need to deal with sessions in your own file.